# How to draw onto a responsive website

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I m trying to create what I hope will be a basic responsive website using Bootstrap 3.0.3. 
I am making a time line, that goes down vertically, when the window is large It has icons on either side of the timeline, otherwise the icons line up and the timeline markers shrink.
Like this:
When Large:
[image]

When Small:

[image]

Currently the Icons and words behave properly, but I had to draw the lines in to illustrate my point. In reality I have | and - representing the lines, and they appear and disappear with resizing. My question is this, how can I draw the actual lines of the timeline so they act properly. Is there some vector or shape drawing I can do within the grid elements or do I just have to draw the lines elsewhere and bring it in as a background image and change that with window resize?

Current Code:

```
<div class="row">
    <h5>WEEK 1</h5>  
</div>
<div class ="row">
    <div class = "col-xs-12 col-sm-2">                
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" rel="popover" data-content="output" data-placement="right" data-trigger="click"><img src="Doc_icon.jpg"></a>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-default" rel="popover" data-content="output" data-placement="right" data-trigger="click"><img src="Drawing_icon.jpg"></a></p>
    </div>
    <div class = "col-sm-1">
        <h3 class="hidden-xs">||</h3>
    </div>
    <div class = "col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">This weeks project tittle</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>Project description: ba nananananana nananananana nananananana nananana nana batman!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>            
    <div class = "col-xs-1 col-sm-3">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "row">
        <h3 class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">---</h3>
        <h3 class="hidden-xs">===</h3>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With my limited experience I would stick with the use of bootstrap framework and responsive rows to get your required design.  I have made up a quick jfiddle below with a basic work up

[JSFiddle of Timeline](http://jsfiddle.net/3F3b6/)

The basic steps were -

1. Add `border-top-bottom` css class to row with following code

   `.border-top-bottom{border-top:2px solid red;border-bottom:2px solid red;}`
2. Add `border-right` css class to left column

   `.border-right{
   border-right:2px solid red;
   padding:10px
   }`
3. Remove margin-padding from `rows` and `panel-info`

   `.panel-info{margin-bottom:-1px;}`

   `.row{padding:0px;}`
4. Then you can adjust the padding and look/feel from there.

Hope this helps.  I am not a CSS expert so I am sure there is a more useful answer out there but this is how I would start

Cheers

Comment: Pretty cool answer. My fist thought was to use JavaScript to check the width of the browser. I like the CSS only answer. Works well for people that may have JS disabled.